# Using the verb leave (somebody/something) to do something

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

I have written these sentences because the number 3 is a little confusing in its meaning.

1. Laura left her native England to live in France [ she is going to live in France]
2. I'll leave Peter to enjoy your book. [Peter will read a book]
3. I left my son with grandpa to see a movie.   [ ?]

Who will go to see a movie, me, or my son?
How to write that sentence if I am who want to see a movie? Or my son wants to see a movie?

Comment: I left my son with his grandpa *so I* could go see a movie.

Comment: The third example is inherently ambiguous. But even if it's the same idiomatic usage as *I'll leave it to you to finish the job* (which doesn't necessarily imply speaker is actually *going* somewhere else), #3 implies nothing at all about whether the boy *wants* to see a movie. Perhaps he knows perfectly well that it's just some boring old movie that his parents and grandparents like (and they want to make sure the "next generation" at least *see* the movie, even if they don't particularly *like* it).

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is somewhat ambiguous without context. It could mean that my son and grandpa stayed behind so that I could go watch a movie, or it could mean that my son and grandpa stayed behind while I left so that the two of them could watch the movie.

Without context, there's no way to know which was the author's intention.

You can rewrite the sentence as "I left my son with grandpa so I could see a movie" (similar to what [Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/33113/lambie) commented) or "I left my son with grandpa so they could see a movie".